# Where do i give rights so that users can cancel print jobs on the print server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, print-server

I'm currently running a Windows 2008 R2 print server.  Everything seems to work fine, except that i can't seem to cancel jobs stuck in the queue.  One of our helpdesk asked me to give them rights to do this, and upon inspection, I couldn't cancel the job either (although I'm sure I could bounce the spooler which would have the same effect).  It seems simple enough when I look online-- go to the print server, open up printer management, right click the server, properties, security and add the person or group you want to have rights.  I've tried adding our helpdesk there as a group, individually, even adding myself and giving myself full rights.  Every option gives me the same result.  When I click "Cancel" or "Cancel All Docuements" I get the following error:

Authentication Failed
The error indicates that the action you chose requires a higher privilege than what you have with your account.
Please contact your system administrator to verify that you have the privilege on the requested action.

As far as I can tell adding the person or group where I was should fix it, but nothing seems to be working when I try it.  I've even tried giving a user full admin rights on that server, putting them in the administrator group...same results.  Anyone have any idea why I'm getting this and how to make it work?  Thank you in advance!

Don

Comment: Did you try logging out/back in? Account permissions require a new login to take hold. Silly question, but worth checking.

Comment: A good suggestion, I've seen issues where that worked before, but sadly i've tried that several times as well with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Add the users to the Print Operators group on the print server.  You'll need to disconnect any active sessions for that user from the server (in computer management > Shared Folders> Sessions) before the new settings will take effect.

Comment: I actually already have Domain Users set as Print Operators, which should encompass everyone on there.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

We add the relevant users group to each printer's security tab. You can then give the group the rights to :-
- Print
- Manage the printer
- Manage the documents

For normal staff, we tick "Print" and "Manage the documents". Manage the documents allows them to delete.

We have around 350 printers! This works across the 6 university campuses we have.

Comment: Does this allow users to delete jobs created by other users, or just their own jobs? I can envision my students deleting other users' jobs as a prank...